# Set y ticks in logscale Boxplots: Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot, ticker

I am plotting boxplots of some data in the range of 0 to 20 on a log scale. I want to set a custom starting and ending ticks. All the other ticks should be in the log scale aswell (2 * 10^-1).

I tried using `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:g}'.format(y)))`
doesn't work
Also

```
ymin = min - 0.1 * (max - min)
ymax = max + 0.1 * (max - min)
plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)
```

gives the warning:

```
Invalid limit will be ignored.
  plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)
```

here is the entire code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import ticker
from math import log, exp

log_scale = True
min = 0
max = 50

atributes = []
for i in [8, 10, 6, 12]:
    att = [i] * 50
    atributes.extend(att)
values = np.random.uniform(1, 20, 200)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Attributes': atributes, 'values': values})
if min is None and max is not None:
    min = df1["values"].min()
if max is None and min is not None:
    max = df1["values"].max()

if min or max is not None:
    df1 = df1[(min <= df1["values"]) & (df1["values"] <= max)]

plt.figure()
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
ax = None

ax = sns.boxplot(x='Attributes', y='values', data=df1, color="white")

if log_scale:
    plt.yscale('log')
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:g}'.format(y)))

if min is not None:
    try:
        min, max = log(min), log(max)
    except ValueError:
        min = 0
        max = log(max)
    ymin = min - 0.1 * (max - min)
    ymax = max + 0.1 * (max - min)
    plt.ylim(exp(ymin), exp(ymax))

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(10.5, 8)
plt.show()
```

Here is how the plot looks like:

[image: Boxplot of atributes]

Comment: `ymin = min - 0.1 * (max - min)` will be problematic for a logscale when this makes `ymin`  zero or negative. You might want to take the `log` of `min` and `max`, do the calculation and then call `exp()`. Also "`set_major_formatter ... ` does not work" is not  a very helpful explanation of the problem you encounter. Probably also `set_minor_formatter` is needed to show the minor ticks.  Could you create a reproducible example?

Comment: I have updated the code. I have also tried implementing what you mentioned, it didn't made much difference!

Comment: But why do you set `min = 0` for a log scale? `log(0)` is minus infinity. What about setting it to `1` or to `0.5`?

Comment: after I set min=0, I donot take log of min so as to avoid the Math Error

Comment: Did you add `ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:g}'.format(y)))` to also show the minor ticks?

Comment: yess, this was the main aim. It doesn't work though.
Do you want me to post image of how I want the plot to look like?

Comment: Doesn't it look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUXCX.png) if you add the minor tick labels?

Comment: Very close. I want in scientific notation (1e-1, 2e-1, 3e-1.....) for values between 0 and 1. Sometimes the value might be very small , say between 0.01 and 0.02, so it should automatically use (1e-3, 2e-3, 3e-3...). All minor ticks between 2 major ticks are not necessary, it should be as per the y scale, sufficiently spacious.